# How should i propertly use angular templates (ng-include)?

Tags: angularjs

I made html template and want to use it with angular via ng-include.

```
<input class="k-textbox" ng-model="entity.Name">
```

i want to use it twice, so i added it into page like this

```
<div ng-include="'/template.html'" ng-init="entity=firstEntity"></div>
<div ng-include="'/template.html'" ng-init="entity=secondEntity"></div>
```

But as a result i getting 2 templates with 'secondEntity' as data, what is proper usage?

Comment: Check my edit to see if that achieves what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a possible usage:

JS:

```
app.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
  $scope.entity = firstEntity;
}

app.controller("myCtrl2", function($scope) {
   $scope.entity = secondEndity;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
   <div ng-include="'/template.html'"></div>
</div>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl2">
  <div ng-include="'/template.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Although, reusable templates that require passing different models or configuration are achieved using directives.

EDIT: Directive approach:

JS:

```
app.controller("myCtrl1", function($scope) {
  $scope.entities = {entity1: {}, entity2: {}};
}


app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      entity: '='
    },
    template: '<input class="k-textbox" ng-model="entity.Name">'
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl1">
   <myDirective entity="entities.entity1"></myDirective>
   <myDirective entity="entities.entity2"></myDirective>
</div>
```

Comment: So i get two entities in different scopes, can i join them to have as a result object with both entities?

Comment: What do you mean join them?

Comment: i need to have ` { entity1: {}, entity2 : {}}` as a result

Comment: @Horosho You would probably need to use a directive in that case.